# Установка текста в GtkEntry

Tags: linux, c, gtk, кросс-компиляция

Столкнулся с непонятной для себя проблемой. Читаю [документацию](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.12/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-text):

```
const gchar *
gtk_entry_get_text (GtkEntry *entry);
```

вижу что функция принимает указатель **GtkEntry**. Далее, пишу форму в глайде:

```
    ...
    <child>
     <object class="GtkEntry" id="txtMatrixSize"> <!-- ясно видно что это именно GtkEntry -->
       <property name="visible">True</property>
       <property name="can_focus">True</property>
       <property name="valign">center</property>
       <property name="max_length">3</property>
       <property name="max_width_chars">3</property>
       <property name="text" translatable="yes">45</property>
       <property name="shadow_type">none</property>
       <property name="primary_icon_activatable">False</property>
       <property name="secondary_icon_activatable">False</property>
       <property name="primary_icon_sensitive">False</property>
       <property name="secondary_icon_sensitive">False</property>
     </object>
     <packing>
       <property name="expand">False</property>
       <property name="fill">False</property>
       <property name="position">1</property>
     </packing>
    </child>
    ...
```

далее, MainForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cairo.h>

   #define UI_FILE "Forms/mainForm.glade"

    // Струкутура контроллов на форме
    typedef struct CControls {

        GtkEntry *txtMatrixSize; // тип указателя GtkEntry

    } Controls;

    // Структура формы
    typedef struct CMainForm {

        GtkBuilder *builder;
        GtkWidget  *mainWindow;

        Controls controls;

    } MainForm;

    extern void OpenForm(int,char**,MainForm);
```

код простейшей программы с установкой текста:

```
#include "MainForm.h"

    MainForm form;

    void initControls(MainForm mainForm) {

        mainForm.controls.txtMatrixSize = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(mainForm.builder, "txtMatrixSize")); // получаю Entry из разметки, пытаюсь привести его к указателю на GtkEntry

    }

    void OpenForm(int argc, char **argv, MainForm mainForm){
        GError *error = NULL;
        gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

        mainForm.builder = gtk_builder_new();

            if(!gtk_builder_add_from_file(mainForm.builder,UI_FILE,&error)) {
                g_warning( "%s", error->message );
                g_free( error );
                return;
            }

        mainForm.mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainForm.builder, "mainForm"));
        initControls(mainForm);

        gtk_entry_set_text(mainForm.controls.txtMatrixSize,"123"); // пытаюсь установить текст

        gtk_builder_connect_signals(mainForm.builder,NULL);

        g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(mainForm.builder));
        gtk_widget_show(mainForm.mainWindow);

        gtk_main();

    }
```

Собственно, собирается всё успешно, далее, я получаю следующую ошибку:

> (pathfinder:2735): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

Аналогичное поведение ("объект не является GtkWidget") происходит, например, если я пытаюсь [установить размер виджета](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-size-request)

Такое ощущение, что я не правильно скастовал GTK_ENTRY, но, других примеров найти не могу. Подскажите, что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы работает со структурой  в стеке поэтому У Вас не сохранеется адрес на GtkEntry, более правильно работать через указатели

```
#include "MainForm.h"

MainForm form;

void initControls(MainForm * mainForm) {

    mainForm->controls->txtMatrixSize = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(mainForm.builder, "txtMatrixSize")); // получаю Entry из разметки, пытаюсь привести его к указателю на GtkEntry

}

void OpenForm(int argc, char **argv, MainForm *mainForm){
    GError *error = NULL;
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    mainForm->builder = gtk_builder_new();

        if(!gtk_builder_add_from_file(mainForm->builder,UI_FILE,&error)) {
            g_warning( "%s", error->message );
            g_free( error );
            return;
        }

    mainForm->mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainForm->builder, "mainForm"));
    initControls(mainForm);

    gtk_entry_set_text(mainForm->controls->txtMatrixSize,"123"); // пытаюсь установить текст

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(mainForm->builder,NULL);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(mainForm->builder));
    gtk_widget_show(mainForm->mainWindow);

    gtk_main();

}
```

Сразу не заметил вызов функции.

Comment: >>Вы работает со структурой в стеке<< точно, именно здесь и решил упростить, сейчас перепроверю...

Comment: Действительно всё так. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @test123 Мне както glade не понравился Я его не использую, не удобно когда настройки объекта  в разных файлах находятся.

Comment: Пока альтернатив не встречал, gtk начал учить неделю назад, так что опыта нет.

Comment: После 3-4 окошек привыкаешь к методам расположения в GTK и уже первичное отображение не нужно.

Comment: Есть такое, слои в любом языке удобно верстать кодом. В той же java и в том же шарпе (unity) их и использую, на си, пока что, сложно - надо layout-ы поучить